# Error with Google Map and ViewPagers

Tags: android, android-viewpager, maps, fragment

I have a ViewPager with one Fragment is a ListView and another the map when i try add the map app crash, i try with the support-library and without.. not works so i will put the error log if someone knows thnks.

```
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463): Process: com.infosports.actividadesdeportivasb, PID: 13463
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463): java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at com.infosports.fracss.FracMap.onCreateView(FracMap.java:24)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16537)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5135)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16537)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1226)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:326)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16537)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5135)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16537)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5135)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16537)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5135)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16537)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1947)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1137)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1326)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1024)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5796)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRunleme istime(13463):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    05-26 16:21:50.595: E/AndroidRuntime(13463):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**i guess the problem is here in th class**

```
public class FracMap extends Fragment {
        View rootView;
       MapFragment mapView;
       // GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frac_maps, container, false);
        GoogleMap mapa = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        return rootView;

    }

    public static FracMap map(){

        return new FracMap();
    }
}
```

**the manifest.xml**

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.infosports.actividadesdeportivasb"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
<permission 
android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
<uses-permission 
android:name="com.infosports.actividadesdeportivasb"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />  
      <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
     <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/path3190"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="got this"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


          <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.infosports.actividadesdeportivasb.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
             android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
              android:name="com.infosports.actividadesdeportivasb.SelectedActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

         <activity
              android:name="com.infosports.actividadesdeportivasb.InfoNews"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**the layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: Please post `R.layout.frac_maps.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the using of this specific `SupportMapFragment` class in the layout, you have to deal with the `getSupportMapFragment()` method as follows:

```
GoogleMap mapa = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: yeah was that you are best :D,  and im a newbiew thank you very much.

Comment: No need to get the `FragmentManager` by referencing the `Activity`. You can just call `getFragmentManager()` from inside the `Fragment` itself.

Comment: Are you sure @Emmanuel? Because if you use the class `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`, you must use `getSupportFragmentManager()` method and not `getFragmentManager()`. Maybe I'm wrong and I will be glad to know my mistake however I always use this instead of other.

Comment: That is the case if you are calling the method inside an `Activity`. Here he is inside a `Fragment`. `Fragments` have their own `getFragmentManager()`, and in the case of a support library `Fragment` it will return the support library version of the `FragmentManager` as the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getFragmentManager()) say.

Comment: thanks  for you  answer Emmanuel, i´m just  starting with android, i had error there and FIlo was right but you also, not needed getActivity, already tested. so thank you both.